# Cytoscape content background

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am wondering if it is possible to set the background color of an edge label with cytoscape? I am setting the rest of the edge styles like this.

```
    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
        .selector("edge")
            .css({
                "line-color": "#444444",
                "width": 4,
                "content": "data(length)"
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an outline on edge labels: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels